# Music Players with Equalizer Almost Killing Battery on nubia

Tags: battery, battery-life, music-player, poweramp

It's a nubia Z9 max Elite (NX518J) equipped with Qualcomm's Burndragon 810 SoC running nubia's stock ROM.

I just installed and tried out Poweramp and it's amazing. However my phone got hot considerably quickly. After unplugging it from wired power, it drained 1% battery in less than even 1 minute. I then got rid of Poweramp without killing other backgrounds, my phone managed to survive for more than 7 minutes with 1%.

Later I installed Poweramp back and turned off equlizer, and the battery consumption fell to a reasonable speed. So it's surely equalizer's fault.

Ah, yes. I can remember that Musixmatch had the same issue if equalizer was turned on. So there's nothing to do with Poweramp.

Can anyone help explain this phenomenon? Quite a bunch of music players have this issue. It's confusing.

Comment: Good that you figured it out. Deleting my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's the manufacturer, nubia's fault.

nubia pretty makes a lot of non-regular functions in their ROMs, namely nubia UI. It implements its own fingerprint API (which is not compatible with any existing ones), its own charging detection and its own immersive status bar. This time it's nubia's own music effects API.

Both Poweramp and Musixmatch calls AOSP's MusicFX API for equalizers, but on nubia this does not exist. So everything that should have been done by DAC is done by CPU instead. Adding that Snapdragon 810 is a burny stuff, the phone gets hot very quickly.